# Is it possible to flatten json file in Data factory copy activity?

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file looks like below, I am not supposed to use data flow. Is it possible to flatten the file using copy activity in azure data factory?

```
{
        "domain_scores": [
            {
                "abc": [
                    10.5,
                    10.5,
                    10.5
                ],
                "def": [
                    16.38,
                    16.38,
                    16.38
                ],
                "name": "level1"
            },
            {
                "abc": [
                    10.5,
                    10.5,
                    10.5
                ],
                "def": [
                    16.38,
                    16.38,
                    16.38
                ],
                "name": "level2"
            },
            {
                "abc": [
                    10.5,
                    10.5,
                    10.5
                ],
                "def": [
                    16.38,
                    16.38,
                    16.38
                ],
                "name": "level3"
            }
        ],
        "tags": [
            "Data",
            "Dimension",
            "Process"
        ],
        "range": {
            "min": 10.5,
            "max": 16.375
        }
    }
```

or is there any other way to flatten the file in data factory?

Answer (score 1):

But copy activity only pulls the first row of the array and not all the rows.
I believe only dataflow can do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31280882)